# JSF-PrimeFaces file upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, apache-commons-fileupload

I have been looking for a solution for my problem everywhere but nothing seems works in my case. My Problem is the following:

I'm attempting to create in my web application (working with JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 5.1 on Apache Tomcat 8 server) an uploading file system. These are my files:

XHTML:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myBean.manageUpload}"
                  mode="advanced"
                  dragDropSupport="true"
                  multiple="true"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
</h:form>
```

backging bean:

```
public void manageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getFile().getFileName() + " uploaded");
}
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have both libraries commons-io 2.4 and commons-fileupload 1.3.1

When I try to upload a file, clicking on "choose", I am able to choose the file to upload but when I select it simply nothing happens. The method `manageUpload()` is never invoked.

Thanks all.

**SOLVED**

Simply there was an error in my XHTML page that prevent the submission of the form.

Comment: Yes, i had already read this answer but nothing. The file upload in mode="simple" works good, but if i try to use the advanced one nothing works.

Comment: Ok, i have read better the question linked before but my situation is a little bit different: in that case the method in the bean  "isn't being invoked after the upload finishes". In my case the upload never start!! I'm able only to choose the file to upload. When i click "ok" in the file chooser window nothing appens! As you suggest, i have tried to check HTTP traffic but, when i try to activate the file upload form nothing change! It is completely ignored..

Comment: I also putted a breakpoint in the primefaces code at the begging of FileUploadRenderer#decode() and ... surprise! not even this methos is invoked!

Comment: Yes i know, I use JSF 2.2 and i tried to use both commons and native, with and without filter, but the result is the same..

Comment: Ok I solved, there was an error in my xhtml page that prevent the submission of the form. Thank you anyway!!